# Reference to be add

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Which reference do I add to use `Recordset` object in Excel VBA?

I tried adding **`Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`** reference but still it's not working.

Comment: Try Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects - Although it may help to see what you are trying to use? or do? or some information/context ?

Comment: Tell me more. What is your main error. Is it shown compile error? What is error. If compile error is not shown, you should show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Microsoft Access 12.0 (or higher) Object Library". Be sure to set the DAO library to a lower priority or dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library
```

Or

```
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library
```